# fullPage.js gradient backgrounds

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, fullpage.js

I'm using `fullPage.js` in my Custom WordPress theme.
I want to change the background-color to a gradient but I don't know how to disable the default background-color.

Because of WordPress I use a loop to create the pages.
A counter starts at `0` and adds up based upon the pages used. Every page get's an `id` named `section` and the counted number. So `id="section0"`

In my style sheet I added gradients with the ID name.

```
#section0{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top left, bottom left, from(#4bbfc3), to(#7baabe));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4BBFC3, #7BAABE);
    background: linear-gradient(#4BBFC3,#7BAABE);
}
```

If I load the page the changes won't take effect because `fullPage.js` already sets the background. There is a function which adds an inline background style to the section.

```
sectionsColor: ['#edf0da','#aa4465','#a89b8c','#f0dfad','#8f5c38'],
```

If I delete this line the entire background is white and still not using my gradients.

Can anyone tell me how to disable the default color option in `fullPage.js` so I can use my gradients?

Comment: add `!important` to your style

Comment: Don't you ever say that to me again.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

I used an inline background image to the section. This overruled the entire style sheet. If I remove the inline background image the changes take effect.....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [gradientsBackgrounds.html example provided by fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/gradientBackgrounds.html).

Comment: Yeah I saw this and did the exact same thing. Problem is that it didn't work because I used a inline background style